# What to do about this Error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, json, plugins

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     C:\Users\Remy Jr\AndroidStudioProjects\KALA3\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\Remy Jr\AndroidStudioProjects\KALA3\app\google-services.json

I've installed the Google plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Firebase Assistant**

To open the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio:

1. Click Tools > Firebase to open the Assistant window.
2. Click to expand one of the listed features (for example, Analytics), then click the Connect to Firebase tutorial to connect to Firebase and add the necessary code to your app.

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup